# Как изменить язык?

Tags: html

В HTML-документе почему-то не могу изменить язык содержимого.Пишу:   <html lang="ru"> .

Comment: и? язык чего хочется поменять? сделать перевод странички? :))))

Comment: Да.Меняю с английского на русский, но не получается...

Comment: @artyom такое только в сказках бывает, чтобы по взмаху палочки всё переводилось :-)

Comment: Понимаю, но что делать?

Comment: погуглить на тему онлайн переводчиков для сайта)

Comment: пацталом)))))

Comment: Какое изящное решение))

Answer (score 2):

Браузер сам по себе не может перевести текст с одного языка на другой. Он, в принципе, и не понимает, что написано в странице, кроме тэгов, скриптов и стилей. 
Если вам надо сделать сайт на нескольких языках (или перевести страницу), рекомендую прочесть статью про google translate ([Перевести страницу на другой язык](http://vladtimoshenko.com/ustanovit-perevodchik-na-sajt-google-translate/))